# 病院に行きます　or 病院へ行きます?

Tags: usage

which one is correct, or more commonly used?

`病院に行きます`  or   `病院へ行きます`??

when should I use `へ` instead of `に`? Thanks!

Comment: に　I think is better, a novice here too... But my understanding: に is generally better especially with specific places like 病院。Whereas a less specific place he is OK: 京都へ行くます. Again, still pretty novice in case someone comes along and completely refutes this ;)

Comment: Since we already have a question that's substantially the same, I've linked this one as a duplicate.  If anyone would like to add anything, please do it on an answer over there so we can keep all our answers in one place :-)  Thank you!

Comment: 両方正しいです。日常生活の上では「病院に行きます」も「病院へ行きます」も同じです。会話では「病院に行きます」のほうをよく聞きます。丁寧な文章を書くときは「病院へ行きます」のほうが好まれると思います。「京都へ行きます」「京都に行きます」も両方使えます。